# Getting OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exception when using ActiveRecord::find_in_batces (20 records a time)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, jrubyonrails

I am using: 
Rails 3.0.7
jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357)

and trying to process ~360K DB records in batches of 20, as following:

```
BackJobs.find_in_batches(:conditions => "progress = -1", :batch_size => 20) do |all_pending_jobs|
    all_pending_jobs.each do |job|
        pending_jobs.push(job)
    end
```

however keep getting the exception after some time:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit 
exceeded: SELECT  "background_jobs".* FROM "background_jobs" WHERE (progress = -1) 
AND ("background_jobs"."id" > 45256) ORDER BY "background_jobs"."id" ASC LIMIT 20
```

the process runs with those JVM settings:
-Xmx256m -Xss2048k

As far as I understand, active_record.identity_map is not supported until rails 3.1.0
[Ruby on Rails memory leak when looping through large number of records; find_each doesn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668875/ruby-on-rails-memory-leak-when-looping-through-large-number-of-records-find-eac)

But even using ActiveRecord::Unchached only does not help..

Not sure if I should/how to destroy ActiveRecord objects to free memory. Please advise. Thanks.