# How can I prevent my Rails query from maxing out memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, activerecord, ssh

I'm sshing into a server running my Rails app in order to run queries. Despite using `find_each`, the server's memory is getting eaten up by my console session and I'm not sure why. [Based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668875/ruby-on-rails-memory-leak-when-looping-through-large-number-of-records-find-eac/6682326#6682326), I'm also using `ActiveRecord::Base.uncached` to prevent ActiveRecord from caching all the objects and eating up memory.

*Edit:* Figured it out, thanks to @user2864740 and Micah Fivecoate. The issue was with sending off tasks to Resque, which I'm doing with the Resque Delayable gem (See answer below).

Here's what I'm doing:

```
ssh cron.ec2.company-name.com
cd /var/www/company-name.com/current; bundle exec rails console production
```

Then, in the console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
  ModelObject.find_each do |obj|
    a = AnotherModelObject.find_by_model_id(obj.id)
    a ||= AnotherModelObject.create!(obj.id)
    a.send_task_to_resque
  end
end
```

As soon as I kill my SSH session, the memory is freed up.

I'm running Rails 3.2.15 with ruby 1.9.3p327 on Linux.

I'm getting the text of all the SQL queries sent back to me over the SSH session—maybe this is kept in memory or something? Next I might try with `conf.echo = false` and `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1`. *Edit: This didn't fix the memory usage*

Comment: Perhaps too many things are getting sent to resque "too fast"? (I'm not sure how resque works, but I suspect that it's related.) Sending the query text back to an IO/SSH stream ought not to build up any pressure as that *will* block when the buffers fill.

Comment: @user2864740 You were right; sending the query text back made no difference. Good call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with sending tasks to Resque. Thanks to @user2864740 for having this idea.

First I tested by using an empty `find_each` block, and that didn't cause memory growth. Then I tried a `find_each` block that created an ActiveRecord object, and that didn't cause memory growth.

Finally I tested doing a `find_each` over records and sending off a task to resque. This alone caused the memory to steadily climb and not fall. I should have also mentioned that I'm using the [ResqueDelayable](https://github.com/loopj/resque-delayable) gem to dispatch tasks to resque, and it might be implicated by this.